# EMACS how to reset buffer-modified flag when buffer is equal file

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to reset the buffer-modified flag when buffer is equal to the file but is marked as modified?  In this case I want emacs don't ask me for save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have `diff` installed, this will do it:

```
(defun my-update-modified-flag ()
  "Update the buffer modified flag."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buffer (current-buffer))
         (basefile
          (or (buffer-file-name buffer)
              (error "Buffer %s has no associated file" buffer)))
         (tempfile (make-temp-file "buffer-content-")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (save-restriction
        (widen)
        (write-region (point-min) (point-max) tempfile nil 'silent)))
    (if (= (call-process "diff" nil nil nil basefile tempfile) 0)
        (progn
          (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
          (message "Buffer matches file"))
      (message "Buffer doesn't match file"))
    (delete-file tempfile)))
```

Comment: @scottfrazer  What about hooking a non-interactive version up to `kill-buffer-query-functions`?

Comment: Hi scottfrazer. I apologize a lot for the delay to accept the answer, (I have understood only now the mechanism). It's a very useful function for me

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @scottfrazer's answer, I wrote a set of functions to automatically check if buffers that are associated with files should be updated to 'unmodified':

## [`unmodified-buffer.el`](https://github.com/arthurcgusmao/unmodified-buffer)

A few improvements on the original code are:

- Compare file size first to avoid unnecessary run of diff/creation of temp files;
- Limit size of files to be compared to 50kb for good performance;
- Hooks to automatically perform state updates when necessary;
- Timer calls to make checking run only after an idle time period;
- `combine-after-change-calls` so that Emacs can handle `'after-change-functions` hook more efficiently.

To be honest I am not so experienced with Elisp although I have been hacking with Emacs for a few years. I would appreciate very much the community's feedback to help improve this. Hope this can help!

Comment: I installed Arthur's unmodified-buffer.el package via MELPA using `M-x package-install RET unmodified-buffer` and then I added the lines `(require 'unmodified-buffer)` and `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'unmodified-buffer-global-mode)` to my init file to enable it, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression:

```
(set-buffer-modified-p nil)
```

Beware! It clears the flag even if the buffer **was** really modified.

Comment: There's a command `not-modified` which is bound to `M-~`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#index-M_002d_007e-995